# How do I add a "play again" feature to my C++ guessing game? Loop trouble

Tags: c++, loops, numbers

So for this assignment I have to include a play again function. Meaning once the person has guessed correctly the program should give the user the choice to play again or not. Also, I am trying to include a function where if the user guesses correctly in 5 guesses or less, then the program should print "Good Job!" and if it takes them more than 5 guesses, it should display "You can do better than that!". Help me please! I am a beginner in programming and I keep getting stuck in trying to fix this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void )
{

int i, n = 0, r;
int answer;
srand( time( NULL ) );
r = rand() %100 +1;
char userName[15];


printf("Welcome to GUESS MY NUMBER!\n\nPlease type your name here: ");
scanf("%s", &userName);
printf("\n\nI am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n\nCan you guess what it is?  ");
while(scanf("%d", &i))
{      
if (n >= 9 && i != r)
{         
printf("\n\nSorry, the number was %d.\n", r);
printf("You should have gotten it by now.\n");        
printf("Better luck next time.\n\n");         
system ("PAUSE");
break;    
}      
if (i > r) 
{         
n++;
printf("Your guess is high. You only get 10 guesses. Try again: ");   
}     
else if (i < r) 
{         
n++;          
printf("Your guess is low. You only get 10 guesses. Try again: ");    
}     
else if (i == r) 
{             
printf("\n\nCongratulations %s!\nYou guessed the number within %d guesses!\nWould you  like to play again? y/n?\n",userName, n+1,answer);
scanf("%d", &answer);

system ("PAUSE");
break;         
}    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well a lot of your code (including the random number generation) is not within a loop. If you want code to repeat it has to be part of a loop.. Then you could break out when the conditions are right.

Answer (score 1):

An easy thing to do is create a bool variable (originally set to true) which can be checked in the while statement and updated after the user has been given the option to continue or not. Then just change your breaks into continues and you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in another loop, and at the end of this outer loop, ask the user if he wants to play again. Either a while() or do-while() loop. If the user says yes, continue looping, otherwise exit the loop.

```
-Initialize the game
-Load any resources needed (in this case, none)

Begin looping continually
    - Handle input
    - Think
    - Show results
End looping if exited

-Free any resources (in this case, none)
-Exit
```